# Help With Some Easy JavaScript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, loops, hide, while-loop

I really need help on this one. I have two text with a submit button. Say "Sam" and "Ram" with a submit button next to each one of them.

Now I check my database if the name is present, and if the query is true, I run a for loop to display the two buttons. On the click of any of the buttons, I am storing the number "1" in the db against the name and hiding the element and diplaying another text like "Thanks".

The thing works fine, but when I have two or more text with buttons, only one is being chnaged while the other remains as it is.

Code -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM revbut WHERE onuser='$u'"; 

$g = mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
$geez = mysqli_fetch_array($g);
mysqli_select_db($connect,"users");
//using for the display of the offer box
$db = "SELECT * FROM but WHERE sessionusername='$u'"; 

$s = mysqli_query($connect,$db) or die(mysqli_error($connect));

$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($s);
$number = mysqli_num_rows($g);
for($i = 0; $i<$number;$i++)
{

if($geez['onuser']) {
 $globalname = $geez['sessionusername'];
    require('djser.php');
}
else if($user['sessionusername'])
{
include('djser2.php'); 
}
```

}

INSIDE the DJER.PHP

JAVASCRIPT

```
if(<?php echo json_encode($re=='reject'); ?>){
 //if response is reject
    document.getElementById('hide').style.display = "none"; 
 document.getElementById('onapprove').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('onreject').style.display="block";
}

else if(<?php echo json_encode($re=='approve'); ?>){
 //if response is approve
 document.getElementById('hide').style.display = "none"; 
 document.getElementById('onapprove').style.display = "block";
}
```

it works fine for one. when two are involved, only the upper one is changed.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a screenshot of the interface with two or more buttons? I can't quite picture the exact functionality/issue.

Comment: You should not have erased your question and replaced it with "Got the answer!" Now, other people that may have had similar problems or questions cannot refer to this question for help in the future. The proper thing to do would have been to answer the question yourself in one of the boxes below.

Comment: If you want to delete a question, then delete it (AFAIK you can so long as there aren't any answers). Don't deface it.

Comment: @David Beat me to it! Thanks for salvaging what he had deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Take off the else

```
if(<?php echo json_encode($re=='reject'); ?>){
 //if response is reject
    document.getElementById('hide').style.display = "none"; 
 document.getElementById('onapprove').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('onreject').style.display="block";
}

if(<?php echo json_encode($re=='approve'); ?>){
 //if response is approve
 document.getElementById('hide').style.display = "none"; 
 document.getElementById('onapprove').style.display = "block";
}
```

If the top one get's changed, that means that condition passed so in an if elseif the second condition won't get checked or executed.

Also, use something other than json_encode, that will create and object with a value that will always evaluate to true (even if the content of the object is the false value).